# Is it possible to return True in for loop?

Tags: python, return-type

In this code, I am taking two numbers in the list and checking whether it is adding up to K. The only problem is that I am not able to return True.

but if I use the print function instead of return it works. Is there some constraint that I cannot use return type in for loop or conditions?

```
def funcSum():
    NumList = []

    Number = int(input("Please enter the total number of list elements: "))
    for i in range(1, Number + 1):
        value = int(input("Please enter the value of %d element : " %i))
        NumList.append(value)

    k = int(input("Enter the value of K: "))

    for i in range (Number):
        for j in range(i + 1, Number):
            if NumList[i] + NumList[j] == k:
                return True
                break
funcSum()
```

I want to return True if two numbers add up to K or it will return False.

Comment: Print the return value ; `print(funcSum())`

Comment: Yes, you can return in a loop. You're not printing the result of calling the function

Comment: You have to put the `break` then return the value from outside the loop

Comment: how do you check if it works? because it should. also the break after the return is not needed

Comment: Note: you don't need a break after a return, and you should return False outside the loop

Comment: @Romain No you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use your original code :

```
def funcSum():
    NumList = []

    Number = int(input("Please enter the total number of list elements: "))
    for i in range(1, Number + 1):
        value = int(input("Please enter the value of %d element : " %i))
        NumList.append(value)

    k = int(input("Enter the value of K: "))
    equal = False
    for i in range (Number):
        for j in range(i + 1, Number):
            if NumList[i] + NumList[j] == k:
                equal = True
                break
        if equal:
            break
    return equal
```

but you can also do this with the last bit:

```
    equal = False
    for i in list(NumList):
        for u in list(NumList):
            if i == u:
                equal = True
                break
        if equal :
            break
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: In your first example, you're returning `found`, but you're never defining that variable or setting it to a value.  - This will lead to an exception being thrown on the `return found` line.  I bet you mean to be returning `equal`.

Comment: I think the OPs solution is easier to understand and more straightforward.  In terms of if one should return from within a for loop...Guido van Rossum, Python's original author, actually suggests that this is the best solution for breaking out of multiple loops.  He offered this as a rebuttal to the idea of adding labels to allow for multi-level breaks: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html

Comment: @Steve Oh yeah, I forgot to change it, thanks! I'll change it now

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there's nothing at all wrong with returning `True` the way that you are doing so.  Seems to me that you're just missing returning `False` if you never find a match.  I think you just want this:

```
def funcSum():
    NumList = []

    Number = int(input("Please enter the total number of list elements: "))
    for i in range(1, Number + 1):
        value = int(input("Please enter the value of %d element : " %i))
        NumList.append(value)

    k = int(input("Enter the value of K: "))

    for i in range (Number):
        for j in range(i + 1, Number):
            if NumList[i] + NumList[j] == k:
                return True

    return False

funcSum()
```

I took out the `break` that you had in there.  That line was unreachable code, and therefore unnecessary.

Your code could work as-is depending on what you're doing with the return value.  My addition causes 'False' to be returned rather than 'None' in the case where you never match and return 'True'.  In many cases, testing for "falseness" will succeed with a value of either `False` or `None`, so you might have been OK anyway.  But adding the explicit return is very much recommended in any case...it insures that your function will always return a boolean value (either True or False).

Answer (score -2):

It's not a good practice to break a `for` loop -- or at least it's something I try to avoid. So I think one clearer way to do it is to leverage on some existing tools (`itertools.combinations`, `any`),  to avoid writing all the algorithm -- but, as highlighted by other users, it's perfectly fine to use `break` in your `for` loop.

```
import itertools

def func_sum2(num_list, k):
  """Return true if at least the sum of one combination of 2 elements in the list is equal to k.

  Use 
    - `itertools.combinations` to get the list of all combinations of 2 elements in the list
    - `any` to return true when at least one of the elements is Truth

  """
  return any(comb[0] + comb[1] == k 
         for comb in itertools.combinations(num_list, 2))

# Some tests
assert func_sum2([1,2], 3) == True
assert func_sum2([1,2], 4) == False
assert func_sum2([1,2,3], 5) == True
```

### Note

I've skipped in the answer above the part related to get user's inputs to test it more efficiently. So your original code in this format is

```
def func_sum(num_list, k):
    answer = False

    for i in range (len(num_list)):
      for j in range(i + 1, len(num_list)):
        if num_list[i] + num_list[j] == k:
          answer = True
          break
    return answer

# Some tests
assert func_sum([1,2], 3) == True
assert func_sum([1,2], 4) == False
assert func_sum([1,2,3], 4) == True
```

Comment: There is nothing bad about breaking a for-loop. The for-else statement exists exactly based on breaking for-loops

Comment: @Olivier Melançon I've seen codes with lot of breaks and not it's not easy to figure out what it's going on. However I do not want to discuss about that. I just tried to help someone. Thks for the vote. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But can you clarify how you can write this code without breaking the for loop?

Comment: @Romain - Your second code block is flawed in that the `break` will only break out of the inner `for` loop, and then the code will continue on, running the rest of the iterations represented by the outer `for` loop.  Guido van Rossum, Python's original author, suggests that returning from multiple levels of for loops is his preferred method for these cases.  He cited this as a rebuttal to the idea of adding labels to allow break out of multiple levels of loops with a single break:  https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html

Comment: @Steve Perfectly right! It's the reason why I have proposed a simpler approach :-)